# Tikz: defining nodes as other tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to define a shape for nodes in tikz using another tikzpicture.
For instance, I would like to make the following into a node shape called monoid

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (m) [circle,scale=.5,draw] at (0, 0) {};
  \node (i1) at (-1,.5){};
  \node (i2) at (-1,-.5){};
  \node (o) at (1,|-m){};
    \draw [-] (m) to (o);
    \draw [-] (i1) to [out=0, in=135] (m);
    \draw [-] (i2) to [out=0, in=-135] (m);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and be able to use it in another tikzpicture. For example, doing something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(M)[monoid]at(0,0){};
  \draw (-1,0)[out=0,in=180]to(M.i1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If someone could point me to the part of the manual that I need to read in order to do this, it would be great.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Elena

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! This is what `pic`s are for. Instead of a node, define a `pic`. So, basically, the code of the first `tikzpicture` in your question goes into

```
pics/monoid/.style={code={<your code>}}
```

You can move and/or transform the resulting `pic` (more or less) like a node.<sup>1</sup> What does not work is to use periods to separate the anchors from the name of the `pic`, but the pgfmanual suggests using hyphens (see the example on the top part of p. 267 of pgfmanual v3.1.5), which I am doing here. Then something like

```
\pic (M) at (1.2,0.5) {monoid};
 (5.2,-0.5) pic[rotate=30,red](M'){monoid}; 
\draw (-1,0)[out=0,in=180] to (M-i1);
```

works (but I prefer the `\path ... pic ...;` syntax). As you can see, one can now access the `i1` pic coordinate (or "anchor") from outside. (I changed those to become coordinates instead of extended nodes.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/monoid/.style={code={
    \node (-m) [circle,scale=.5,draw] at (0, 0) {};
    \coordinate (-i1) at (-1,.5){};
    \coordinate (-i2) at (-1,-.5){};
    \coordinate (-o) at (1,0|--m){};
    \draw [-] (-m) to (-o);
    \draw [-] (-i1) to [out=0, in=135] (-m);
    \draw [-] (-i2) to [out=0, in=-135] (-m);}}]
 \path (1.2,0.5) pic(M){monoid}
 (5.2,-0.5) pic[rotate=30,red](M'){monoid}; 
 \draw (-1,0)[out=0,in=180] to (M-i1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup>For instance, `positioning` does not work with `pic`s like nodes, basically because Ti*k*Z does not know the boundary paths of the `pic`s.</sub>

Comment: I think it more about the fact that a `pic` doesn't have anchors that `positioning` doesn't work.

Comment: @HenriMenke You are right, that's perhaps a better statement. What I wanted to say is that if you wrap a pic in a `\matrix`, you can position it to some extent. This is because the matrix wraps a rectangle node around it, and this is what's meant by a boundary path. Yet, technically one really needs only the `west` and so on anchors, as you say.